# Checking if a List is Null before getting Count results in -> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to find the number of items present in a list.In order to prevent the null exception.I'm using the `?` operator to check whether  `myBenchmarkMappings` is null before getting its count.

```
 int benchmarkAccountCount =portfolioWrapper.myBenchmarkMappings?.Count;
```

But this results in `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'.` exception

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried doing an explicit cast? or has Visual studio suggested any quick fixes?

Comment: @JosipJuros It has suggested some fix,but why does this happen? I'm only checking for null right ? why do i need to convert int to int?

Comment: Usually that exception happens when you are casting something to `int?` but the method signature is `int`?

Comment: What count do you expect to get when `myBenchmarkMappings` is null? Currently you're getting `null`, which isn't assignable to a non-nullable `int`. If you want something else (say 0), you *have to tell the compiler that*.

Comment: @ikegami I need to assign the count to a Blazor component that only supports `int`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because the `?` operator will return the value or `null`. And you can't assign `null` to int.
You have two options. First is to mark the `int` as `nullable`.
But in this case latter you will need to check if the `int` is null.

```cs
int? benchmarkAccountCount = portfolioWrapper.myBenchmarkMappings?.Count;

if (benchmarkAccountCount == null) 
{
    // null handling
}
```

The second option, which I think is better, you can user the null-coalescing operator `??` and give the `benchmarkAccountCount` a default value in case the list is `null`.

```cs
int benchmarkAccountCount = portfolioWrapper.myBenchmarkMappings?.Count ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

When `.myBenchmarkMappings` is `null`, then `.myBenchmarkMappings?.Count` is also `null`. This means this code could possibly assign a `null` to an `int`, but an `int` can't store a `null`. Change the type to `int?` if you want to accommodate an `int` or `null`.

```cs
int? benchmarkAccountCount = portfolioWrapper.myBenchmarkMappings?.Count;
```

Comment: benchmarkAccountCount  can only be `int` as it needs to be assigned to blazor component that only supports `int`

Comment: Then you will need to stop assigning `null` to it. What would you like to do instead?

Comment: ok... guess my understanding of how `?` works  was wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ?: operator to check if list is null:

```
 int benchmarkAccountCount =portfolioWrapper.myBenchmarkMappings!=null ? portfolioWrapper.myBenchmarkMappings.Count:0;
```